# Evidential difficulties (suspect identified; victim supports action)

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law

I have been reading [crime report](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/445753/hosb0115.pdf) and there are various outcomes to cases. What does it mean when case is closed due to reason:

**Evidential difficulties (suspect identified; victim supports action) ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing but:

1. They're pretty damn sure they know who did it
2. They don't have enough admissible evidence to prove it
3. The victim understands this

Comment: Alternatively quality of the evidence that they have, rather than its quantity (i.e. fruit of the poisoned tree, chain of custody, hearsay, wittiness does not wish to testify). I find it odd that the phrase "victim supports action" is used. My own guess is that the victim is not "pressing" charges. I'm not sure what crime this is, but two possible situations present themselves to me: a) the victim is a necessary witness, but doesn't want to testify, and would rather let the suspect walk, or b) the victim doesn't want the suspect punished, such as if their car was "stolen" by their own child

Comment: The answer by Dale M is correct, except for this part: > 3. The victim understands this This is not what "Victim supports action" means. It actually just means that the victim wants the police to take action against the suspect. If the victim "does not support action" it means that they don't want the suspect to be charged.